# Segmentation fault in pthread_create

Tags: linux, pthreads, shared-libraries

I'm using pthread_create to use a function from shared library. I receive Segmenation fault after the following code executes:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void (*GetVersion)(char *version);

void* draw(void *arg)
{
    void *handle;
    char *error;    

    handle = dlopen ("libOpenKaillera.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fputs (dlerror(), stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    GetVersion = dlsym(handle, "GetVersion");
    if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fputs(error, stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    char version[4];
    kailleraGetVersion(version);
    puts(version);
    dlclose(handle);
    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &draw, NULL);        
    sleep(5000);
    return 0;
}
```

The backtrace command says the following:

```
#0  0xb68e7be0 in ?? ()
#1  0xb7fa9d56 in __nptl_deallocate_tsd () at pthread_create.c:158
#2  0xb7fa9f83 in start_thread (arg=0xb7df0b40) at pthread_create.c:325
#3  0xb7ede4ce in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:129
```

I don't understand what a reason can cause this. Can you help me please?

Comment: Without even a backtrace, no we can't possibly help you. Have you looked in the debugger yet at all?

Comment: I've add the backtrace output in the question

Comment: What did you use for compile and link options?

Comment: gcc main.c -pthread -ldl -o m

Comment: Compile with all waring an `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and fix the source until no more warnings are issued during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

after each calling of `pthread_create`, please remember to call `pthread_join` or `pthread_detach` to tell the thread how to perform termination. normally, please call `pthread_join` before exiting the creating thread (in this case, it is function `main`).

Comment: I added pthread_join in main but the problem still exist. Also if I delete dlclose call everything works well

Comment: @spandei it may be not a problem of threading, but a problem of `dlclose`. if the loaded function brings something to be done on termination, it may produce such problem. you may try to load a simplest `.so` file to investigate it.